# Recursive Promise in javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion, promise

I'm writing a Javascript `Promise` that finds the final redirect URL of a link.

What I'm doing is making a `HEAD` request in a `Promise` using an `XMLHttpRequest`.  Then, on load, check the HTTP Status for something in the 300 range, or if it has a `responseURL` attached to the object and that url is different than the it was one handed.

If neither of these are true, I `resolve(url)`.  Otherwise, I recursively call `getRedirectUrl()` on the response URL, and `resolve()`.

Here's my code:

```
function getRedirectUrl(url, maxRedirects) {
    maxRedirects = maxRedirects || 0;
    if (maxRedirects > 10) {
        throw new Error("Redirected too many times.");
    }

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var p = new Promise(function (resolve) {
        xhr.onload = function () {
            var redirectsTo;
            if (this.status < 400 && this.status >= 300) {
                redirectsTo = this.getResponseHeader("Location");
            } else if (this.responseURL && this.responseURL != url) {
                redirectsTo = this.responseURL;
            }

            if (redirectsTo) {
                // check that redirect address doesn't redirect again
                // **problem line**
                p.then(function () { self.getRedirectUrl(redirectsTo, maxRedirects + 1); });
                resolve();
            } else {
                resolve(url);
            }
        }

        xhr.open('HEAD', url, true);
        xhr.send();
    });

    return p;
}
```

Then to use this function I do something like:

```
getRedirectUrl(myUrl).then(function (url) { ... });
```

The issue is that `resolve();` in `getRedirectUrl` will call the `then()` from the calling function before it calls the `getRedirectUrl` recursive call, and at that point, the URL is `undefined`.

I tried, rather than `p.then(...getRedirectUrl...)` doing `return self.getRedirectUrl(...)` but this will never resolve.

My guess is that the pattern I'm using (that I basically came up with on the fly) isn't right, altogether.

Comment: `p.then(...)` with a function that does not produce any observable side effects and `return`s nothing is meaningless.

Comment: As a general rule, try to avoid doing so much work in the promise constructor. It's rarely what you want, and the problem becomes clearer with regular chains of `then()` and multiple functions.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The problem is that the promise you return from `getRedirectUrl()` needs to include the entire chain of logic to get to the URL. You're just returning a promise for the very first request. The `.then()` you're using in the midst of your function isn't doing anything.

To fix this:

Create a promise that resolves to `redirectUrl` for a redirect, or `null` otherwise:

```
function getRedirectsTo(xhr) {
    if (xhr.status < 400 && xhr.status >= 300) {
        return xhr.getResponseHeader("Location");
    }
    if (xhr.responseURL && xhr.responseURL != url) {
        return xhr.responseURL;
    }

    return null;
}

var p = new Promise(function (resolve) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.onload = function () {
        resolve(getRedirectsTo(xhr));
    };

    xhr.open('HEAD', url, true);
    xhr.send();
});
```

Use `.then()` on *that* to return the recursive call, or not, as needed:

```
return p.then(function (redirectsTo) {
    return redirectsTo
        ? getRedirectUrl(redirectsTo, redirectCount+ 1)
        : url;
});
```

Full solution:

```
function getRedirectsTo(xhr) {
    if (xhr.status < 400 && xhr.status >= 300) {
        return xhr.getResponseHeader("Location");
    }
    if (xhr.responseURL && xhr.responseURL != url) {
        return xhr.responseURL;
    }

    return null;
}

function getRedirectUrl(url, redirectCount) {
    redirectCount = redirectCount || 0;

    if (redirectCount > 10) {
        throw new Error("Redirected too many times.");
    }

    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.onload = function () {
            resolve(getRedirectsTo(xhr));
        };

        xhr.open('HEAD', url, true);
        xhr.send();
    })
    .then(function (redirectsTo) {
        return redirectsTo
            ? getRedirectUrl(redirectsTo, redirectCount + 1)
            : url;
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm confused! I don't see how anything happens here. If I call getRedirectUrl() it returns a promise, and that promise has a resolve() function that does some stuff. And when that stuff is done, may recurse to follow a redirect. But! How does the first xhr.open(); xhr.send() ever happen if the only place it occurs is in the Promise resolve() function? I am still new to promises and JavaScript so may be missing something here.

Comment: @theWebalyst The function with the `xhr.open()` and `xhr.send()` is called before `getRedirectUrl()` returns. The function passed into the `Promise` constructor is called immediately by the `Promise` constructor.

Comment: @theWebalyst Subtle detail here is that the `resolve` function is actually an argument to the handler function passed to the `Promise` constructor. The error in your thinking that causes the confusion is *that promise has a resolve() function that does some stuff.*. Actually, the handler function does some stuff and calls the `resolve` function it was passed when it is done. You could add a second argument named `reject` and call that instead of `throw`ing when there are too many redirects. The effect is the same.

Comment: This is pretty smart, tnx much for advice

Comment: Totally saved me, 5 years later. Thanks!

Answer (score 41):

Here's the simplified solution:

```js
const recursiveCall = (index) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        console.log(index);
        return resolve(index)
    }).then(idx => {
        if (idx < 3) {
            return recursiveCall(++idx)
        } else {
            return idx
        }
    })
}

recursiveCall(0).then(() => console.log('done'));
```

Comment: if index is big enough, you will hit a "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error.

Comment: @balazs well, you can change this `return resolve(recursiveCall(++index))` to `return setTimeout(() => resolve(recursiveCall(++index)), 0);` and you are good to go. But this is not related to the question directly and might be confusing in the simplified example

Comment: Sure, for the use case of the question it won't hit that limit, but for those who want a more general solution (the title of the question sounds general for me) I think it's good to know the limitations.

Comment: @balazs totally agree

Comment: Fantastic, I am having the same issue in different way and on basis of it, it is working fine. Thank you.

Comment: it works but it does not. This piles up nested promises. for me it crashes around 2k recursions. The recursion should be inside the `.then()`.

Comment: @Kameneth thanks, edited according your suggestion

Answer (score 8):

The following has two functions:

- _getRedirectUrl - which is a setTimeout object simulation for looking up a single step lookup of a redirected URL (this is equivalent to a single instance of your XMLHttpRequest HEAD request)
- getRedirectUrl - which is recursive calls Promises to lookup the redirect URL

The secret sauce is the sub Promise whose's successful completion will trigger a call to resolve() from the parent promise.

```js
function _getRedirectUrl( url ) {
    return new Promise( function (resolve) {
        const redirectUrl = {
            "https://mary"   : "https://had",
            "https://had"    : "https://a",
            "https://a"      : "https://little",
            "https://little" : "https://lamb",
        }[ url ];
        setTimeout( resolve, 500, redirectUrl || url );
    } );
}

function getRedirectUrl( url ) {
    return new Promise( function (resolve) {
        console.log("* url: ", url );
        _getRedirectUrl( url ).then( function (redirectUrl) {
            // console.log( "* redirectUrl: ", redirectUrl );
            if ( url === redirectUrl ) {
                resolve( url );
                return;
            }
            getRedirectUrl( redirectUrl ).then( resolve );
        } );
    } );
}

function run() {
    let inputUrl = $( "#inputUrl" ).val();
    console.log( "inputUrl: ", inputUrl );
    $( "#inputUrl" ).prop( "disabled", true );
    $( "#runButton" ).prop( "disabled", true );
    $( "#outputLabel" ).text( "" );
    
    getRedirectUrl( inputUrl )
    .then( function ( data ) {
        console.log( "output: ", data);
        $( "#inputUrl" ).prop( "disabled", false );
        $( "#runButton" ).prop( "disabled", false );
        $( "#outputLabel").text( data );
    } );

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Input:

<select id="inputUrl">
    <option value="https://mary">https://mary</option>
    <option value="https://had">https://had</option>
    <option value="https://a">https://a</option>
    <option value="https://little">https://little</option>
    <option value="https://lamb">https://lamb</option>
</select>

Output:

<label id="outputLabel"></label>

<button id="runButton" onclick="run()">Run</button>
```

As another illustration of recursive Promises, I used it to solve a maze. The `Solve()` function is invoked recursively to advance one step in a solution to a maze, else it backtracks when it encounters a dead end. The `setTimeout` function is used to set the animation of the solution to 100ms per frame (i.e. 10hz frame rate).

```js
const MazeWidth = 9
const MazeHeight = 9

let Maze = [
    "# #######",
    "#   #   #",
    "# ### # #",
    "# #   # #",
    "# # # ###",
    "#   # # #",
    "# ### # #",
    "#   #   #",
    "####### #"
].map(line => line.split(''));

const Wall = '#'
const Free = ' '
const SomeDude = '*'

const StartingPoint = [1, 0]
const EndingPoint = [7, 8]

function PrintDaMaze()
{
    //Maze.forEach(line => console.log(line.join('')))
    let txt = Maze.reduce((p, c) => p += c.join('') + '\n', '')
    let html = txt.replace(/[*]/g, c => '<font color=red>*</font>')
    $('#mazeOutput').html(html)
}

function Solve(X, Y) {

    return new Promise( function (resolve) {
    
        if ( X < 0 || X >= MazeWidth || Y < 0 || Y >= MazeHeight ) {
            resolve( false );
            return;
        }
        
        if ( Maze[Y][X] !== Free ) {
            resolve( false );
            return;
        }

        setTimeout( function () {
        
            // Make the move (if it's wrong, we will backtrack later)
            Maze[Y][X] = SomeDude;
            PrintDaMaze()

            // Check if we have reached our goal.
            if (X == EndingPoint[0] && Y == EndingPoint[1]) {
                resolve(true);
                return;
            }

            // Recursively search for our goal.
            Solve(X - 1, Y)
            .then( function (solved) {
                if (solved) return Promise.resolve(solved);
                return Solve(X + 1, Y);
            } )
            .then( function (solved) {
                if (solved) return Promise.resolve(solved);
                return Solve(X, Y - 1);
             } )
             .then( function (solved) {
                if (solved) return Promise.resolve(solved);
                return Solve(X, Y + 1);
             } )
             .then( function (solved) {
                 if (solved) {
                     resolve(true);
                     return;
                 }

                 // Backtrack
                 setTimeout( function () {
                     Maze[Y][X] = Free;
                     PrintDaMaze()
                     resolve(false);
                 }, 100);
                 
             } );

        }, 100 );
    } );
}

Solve(StartingPoint[0], StartingPoint[1])
.then( function (solved) {
    if (solved) {
        console.log("Solved!")
        PrintDaMaze()
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("Cannot solve. :-(")
    }
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<pre id="mazeOutput">
</pre>
```

Answer (score 5):

Please check below example it will return **`factorial`** of a given number as we did in many programming languages.

I have implemented below example using **`JavaScript`** promises.

```js
let code = (function(){
 let getFactorial = n =>{
  return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
   if(n<=1){
    resolve(1);
   }
   resolve(
    getFactorial(n-1).then(fact => {
     return fact * n;
    })
   )
  });
 }
 return {
  factorial: function(number){
   getFactorial(number).then(
    response => console.log(response)
   )
  }
 }
})();
code.factorial(5);
code.factorial(6);
code.factorial(7);
```

Comment: Working for me.

Answer (score 4):

If you're in an environment that supports `async`/`await` (virtually all modern environments do), you can write an `async function` that looks a bit more like a recursive function pattern we all know and love.  It's not possible to completely avoid a `Promise` due to the nature of `XMLHttpRequest` only retrieving a value via the `load` event (rather than exposing a `Promise` itself), but the recursive nature of the function that makes the call should look familiar.

Having four more years of JavaScript experience than I had when I originally wrote this question, I cleaned up the code a bit, but it works essentially the same way.

```js
// creates a simple Promise that resolves the xhr once it has finished loading
function createXHRPromise(url) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        // addEventListener('load', ...) is basically the same as setting
        // xhr.onload, but is better practice
        xhr.addEventListener('load', () => resolve(xhr));

        // throw in some error handling so that the calling function 
        // won't hang
        xhr.addEventListener('error', reject);
        xhr.addEventListener('abort', reject);

        xhr.open('HEAD', url, true);
        xhr.send();
    });
}

async function getRedirectUrl(url, maxRetries = 10) {
    if (maxRetries <= 0) {
        throw new Error('Redirected too many times');
    }

    const xhr = await createXHRPromise(url);
    if (xhr.status >= 300 && xhr.status < 400) {
        return getRedirectUrl(xhr.getResponseHeader("Location"), maxRetries - 1);
    } else if (xhr.responseURL && xhr.responseURL !== url) {
        return getRedirectUrl(xhr.responseURL, maxRetries - 1);
    }

    return url;
}
```

#### A brief explanation of `async`/`await`

- an `async function` is syntactic sugar for a `Promise`
- `await` is syntactic sugar for `Promise.then()`
- `return` within an `async function` is syntactic sugar for `resolve()`
- `throw` within an `async function` is syntactic sugar for `reject()`

If an `async function` returns either another `async function` call or a `Promise`, the function/promise will resolve before the original call resolves, exactly the same way that resolving a `Promise` would in the `Promise` pattern.

So, you can call `getRedirectUrl(someUrl).then(...).catch(...)` exactly the same way the original question would have.

It should probably be noted that using an XHR to resolve a redirected URL will fail for any URL that doesn't include the proper CORS header.

---

As an added bonus, async/await makes an iterative approach trivial.

```js
async function getRedirectUrl(url, maxRetries = 10) {
    for (let i = 0; i < maxRetries; i++) {
        const xhr = await createXHRPromise(url);
        if (xhr.status >= 300 && xhr.status < 400) {
            url = xhr.getResponseHeader("Location");
        } else if (xhr.responseURL && xhr.responseURL !== url) {
            url = xhr.responseURL;
        } else {
            return url;
        }
    }

    throw new Error('Redirected too many times');
}
```

---

Another note: modern browsers have a [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) function that does essentially what `createXHRPromise()` does, but is more versatile.  It's not supported in node, but there is an npm package called `node-fetch`.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below example for Recursive Promise in javascript/typescript, It will not resolve the promise until number incremented to greater then 13.

below code is suitable for typescript and modify it slightly for javascript.

```
async iterate(number: number): Promise<any> {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let number = 0;
            if (number > 13) {
                // recursive terminate condition
                resolve(number);
                return;
            } else {
                number = number + 1;
                // recursive call
                this.iterate(number).then(resolve);
            }

        });
    }




this.iterate().then((resolvedData: any) => {
           // wait until number is not greater than 13
           console.log(resolvedData);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a nested array structure with asynchronous calls, this solution (built on previous answers) might help. The example runs a setTimeout() for each value it finds in a (possibly) nested array and resolves when it's done with all of them:

```
const recursiveCall = (obj) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        if(obj instanceof Array){
            let cnt = obj.length;
            obj.forEach(el => {
                recursiveCall(el)
                .then(() => {
                    if(!--cnt)return resolve();
                })
                
            });
        } else {
            setTimeout(() => {
                console.log(obj);
                return resolve();
            }, obj);
            
        }
    })
}

recursiveCall([100,50,[10,[200, 300],30],1]).then(() => console.log('done'));

>1
>10
>30
>50
>100
>200
>300
>done
```

Comment: Based on your code, I'm guessing you're fairly new to JavaScript?  If you're interested, I wrote up some commented examples of the "JavaScript way to write this" using declarative functional programming rather than imperative procedural programming. https://codepen.io/dfoverdx/pen/bGreoXK?editors=1111